# Google managed Prometheus migration issue - No matches for kind "PodMonitoring" in version "monitoring.googleapis.com/v1"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, google-cloud-metrics

I'm trying to migrate from GKE workload metrics to Managed Service for Prometheus metrics.

To do this I deploy a PodMonitoring resource to emit metrics that can be scraped by Prometheus following the [Migrating from GKE workload metrics to Managed Service for Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/gmp-migration) doc by Google (using same version as they use in the doc).

My service-config.yaml below:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
kind: PodMonitoring
metadata:
  labels:
    deployment_unit: test-unit
    global_label: my-label
  name: my-service
  namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      path: /metrics
      port: http-prometheus
      scheme: http
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
```

But I keep seeing the error in my build when I try to deploy the service.

```
No matches for kind "PodMonitoring" in version "monitoring.googleapis.com/v1"
```

My GKE version is 1.23.14.

Comment: Are you sure Managed Prometheus is enabled on your cluster?

Comment: Ahh yeah that's the solution! I enabled it in my test environment where this code worked. This started happening on a deploy to another environment, in which I hadn't enabled it. Thanks so much.

Comment: If you want, post that as the answer so I can accept it @GariSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have enabled Google Managed Prometheus on your cluster.